# lambda expression v. for loop through specific columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have a dataframe in which some columns contain HTML:

```
claims = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
dates = [
"<b class='table-label'>Filed Date</b><span class='table-content'>10/17/2019</span>",
"<b class='table-label'>Filed Date</b><span class='table-content'>11/10/2019</span>",
"<b class='table-label'>Filed Date</b><span class='table-content'>11/12/2019</span>", 
"<b class='table-label'>Filed Date</b><span class='table-content'>12/07/2019</span>", 
"<b class='table-label'>Filed Date</b><span class='table-content'>12/27/2019</span>" 
]
totals = [
"<b class='table-label'>Claim Value</b><span class='table-content'>$10.00</span>",
"<b class='table-label'>Claim Value</b><span class='table-content'>$20.00</span>",
"<b class='table-label'>Claim Value</b><span class='table-content'>$30.00</span>",
"<b class='table-label'>Claim Value</b><span class='table-content'>$40.00</span>",
"<b class='table-label'>Claim Value</b><span class='table-content'>$50.00</span>"    
]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(claims, dates, totals)),
             columns = ['claims', "dates", "totals"])
```

I want to remove the HTML and retain only the string in `<span class='table-content'>`

After import BeautifulSoup, I created a function:

```
def strip_html(target):
    target = str(target)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(target, "html.parser")
    return (soup.find("span", class_="table-content").get_text())
```

When I run this function through a `for loop` that targets only the two columns with html, it works.

```
target_columns = ["dates", "totals"]
for target in target_columns:
    df[target] = df[target].apply(lambda x: strip_html(x))
```

[image]

But in reality I have many more target columns and a huge df. I need something faster, so I tried this as a `lambda expression`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: strip_html(x) if x.name in target_columns  else x )
```

i get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`

Comment: Where is from the error? From your code snapshot of from you original huge `df`?

Comment: it happens here with this sample data too.

Comment: `x` is not a string but a pandas `Series` so you cannot make a soup and that's why you get an error

Comment: So why does it work when you `for loop` through the data frame also using x and lambda expression?

Comment: 1) you could try to clean the data before adding them in the `df`. Smt like `df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(claims, map(strip_html, dates), map(strip_html, totals)) ....` 2) @your last comment: the 1st was acting on a column the last try on the full frame

Comment: @cards, do you want to add your response as an answer...I can accept it as the answer. It works, as does my `for loop` and i was really looking for something pythonic and fast. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extraction of the text from the tag can be done before loading the data in the dataframe by performing the scraping function elementwise with `map`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(claims, map(strip_html, dates), map(strip_html, totals), columns=['claims', "dates", "totals"])))
```